# Count images inside a div, then add another/new img src (file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I'm currently using Flask for my back-end coding, and working on my front-end as of now. Below are the images uploaded on the server. Now I need to edit those images, like I need to upload another image or change the existing image. We're using a cropper.js on this one, and I don't know how will I manage this one because I'm not that good when it comes to front-end scripting like javascript/jquery/ajax. Maximum images can upload is up to 8 images, I need to count the total existing images, then add another img src file, for example if I had 3 images, then I need to show 5 more img src file for adding new images. Any help will do and will be appreciated. Below is my code on HTML with Jinja2 template.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
          <label class="rs-thumb rs-thumb-cover">
            <div class="rs-thumb-content" id="inputImage1-wrap"><img src="{{ resource.image_url }}" alt="" id="inputImage1-pic" width="100%"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
              <span class="rs-cover">Cover</span>

            </div>
          </label>
        </div>

        {% for imgs in resource.images[1:] %}
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <label class="rs-thumb rs-thumb-cover">
            <div class="rs-thumb-content" id="inputImage1-wrap"><img src="{{ imgs.image }}" alt="" id="inputImage1-pic" width="100%"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
              <!-- <span class="rs-cover">Cover</span> -->

            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

[Image for Edit Module on front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIBzD.png)

Comment: Do you have any javascript/jquery code written? If yes then please create a fiddle. It will help you get the answer quickly.

Comment: Thank you again @Xarierz. It's pretty working now. I just changed your $("img").length to its element name, and it worked really fine. Now my only problem is on how to remove the existing images, like I wanted to change the existing images with new one, and upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html + JQuery solution, mostly tested so *should* work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgBox">
<!-- Your content will appear here -->
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
// Get the amount of images on the current page
var amountOfImg = $("img").length;
var amountToCount = 8;

for (var i = 0; i < amountToCount - amountOfImg; i++) {
 $(".imgBox").append("<input type='file' name='fileInput' /> <b id='removeImg'>Remove</b>")

}

$("#removeImg").click(function() {
  // When the user clicks on the #removeImg text, find the closest "img" element and remove it.
  $(this).closest("img").remove();

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Xariez. Will try this one.

Comment: Thank you again @Xarierz. It's pretty working now. I just changed your $("img").length to its element name, and it worked really fine. Now my only problem is on how to remove the existing images, like I wanted to change the existing images with new one, and upload it.

Comment: Yeah, some names probably has to be changed but great you got that figured out. I'll edit my answer to something that should work in just a moment, and if it works, please do accept it as an answer! @JJ186021